# Bootstrap popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap and encountered some problem in opening the popup.

This is the code that I used:

```
 <li><a href="#cmvideo" data-toggle="modal">WATCH VIDEO</a></li>



 <div class="modal fade" id="cmvideo" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It was working fine. But I added a jQuery code for smoothly sliding the page to different sections of the page on anchor tag.

This is the code:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    var header = 180;
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - header
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This function works well. But now the popup is not working. Seems it overrides the bootstrap  function. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector on the second line of the smooth-scrolling code to this:

```
'a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([data-toggle="modal"])'
```

That will stop your smooth-scrolling handler from attaching to the modal popup link.

See [this example JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWP7D/).

Comment: Also, I have another question. Is there any way to highlight the nav menus while scrolling down through the pages?

Comment: @user1012181 Check out the docs for [scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).